# Compiler error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with a program, and I'm getting the error above. However, when I search up the error, everyone else has some sort of int * variable whereas I don't have that all compared to them and is still getting this error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

const int VALUES = 250;

using namespace std;

void minFinder(int nums[]);
void maxFinder(int nums[]);
void arithmeticMeanFinder(int nums[]);
void geometricMeanFinder(int nums[]);
void standardDeviationFinder(int nums[]);

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    int number, counter;
    int nums [VALUES];
    counter = 0;
    file.open("F://Yes/Untitled.txt");
    file >> number;
    while (!file.fail()){
        counter++;
        nums [counter-1] = number;
        file >> number;}      
    arithmeticMeanFinder(nums[VALUES]);       
    file.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void arithmeticMeanFinder (int nums[VALUES])
{
     ifstream file;
     int ct, holder;
     double counter, mean;
     double accum = 0;
     for (ct = 0; ct < VALUES; ct++){
         holder = nums[ct];
         accum = accum + holder;
         counter++;}
     mean = (accum * 1.0) / counter;
     cout << counter << " is the arithmetic mean" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code: `arithmeticMeanFinder(nums[VALUES]);` index into `nums` to retrieve the (nonexistent) item at the offset `VALUES`.

I'd guess you want it to be more like: `arithmeticMeanFinder(nums);`

The rest of the code isn't exactly what I'd like (e.g., it requires that the number of values in the file be exactly equal to `VALUES`, or it'll fail miserably), but that's the source of the specific problem the compiler is citing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have:

```
void arithmeticMeanFinder (int nums[VALUES])
```

Because of the rules of C++, this is equivalent to:

```
void arithmeticMeanFinder (int nums[])
```

And also because of the rules of C++, this is equivalent to:

```
void arithmeticMeanFinder (int *nums)
```

So when you call this function, you need to write:

```
arithmeticMeanFinder(nums); // pass the pointer to first element
```

Instead of:

```
arithmeticMeanFinder(nums[VALUES]);
```

In the call to `arithmeticMeanFinder` above, by expression `nums[VALUES]`, you pass the `VALUES`-th element, which is an `int`, as the argument.
As the array `nums` has only `VALUES` items (maximum index is `VALUE - 1`),
this is an out-of-bound access.